# Как плавно сделать обводку обрезанного svg?

Tags: html, svg

Здравствуйте. У блока левый верхний угол 45 градусов, сделал svg с clipPath, но не удается сделать обводку для этого угла. Подскажите как сделать обводку без швов.

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
body {
  background: url(https://arti911.github.io/assets/images/nyamushka/bg.jpg) no-repeat center / cover;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<svg width="350" height="500">
  <line x1="4" y1="44" x2="44" y2="4" stroke="#1698d9" stroke-width="16" />
  <rect x="4" y="4" width="320" height="480" fill="#f2f2f2" stroke="#1698d9" stroke-width="4" rx="10" clip-path="url(#gon)" />
</svg> 

<svg width="0" height="0">
  <clipPath id="gon">
    <polygon points="0,45 45,0 328,0 328,488 -2,488" />
  </clipPath>
</svg>
```

Comment: в данном примере думаю нельзя обвести и clip-path и polygon. Но конкретно в этом примере можно подогнать линию, на глаз тут только толщину до 8 уменьшить и все встанет.

Comment: Сделал пацаны: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PRGyOL

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вариант с псевдоэлементом:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.block {
  margin-top: 15px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: dodgerblue;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(16% 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 50% 100%, 0 100%, 0 16%);
  clip-path: polygon(16% 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 50% 100%, 0 100%, 0 16%);
}

.block::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  left: 5px;
  width: 190px;
  height: 190px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  background-color: #fff;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(16% 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 50% 100%, 0 100%, 0 16%);
  clip-path: polygon(16% 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 50% 100%, 0 100%, 0 16%);
}
```

```html
<div class="block"></div>
```

Comment: хорошее решение, но мы ещё живем в мире где существует IE11. Мое первое решение было сделано через clip-path https://arti911.github.io/case/nyamushka/ , а после просмотра в IE11, погрузился в мир svg

Comment: @АртурП. тогда конечно `svg` подходит для решения этой задачи, если вы интересуетесь этим направлением, можете приходить в чат  про SVG и только https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70612/svg-chat

Answer (score 4):

Пацаны все готово

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
body {
  background: url(https://arti911.github.io/assets/images/nyamushka/bg.jpg) no-repeat center / cover;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="350" height="500">
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="gon">
      <polygon points="0,45 45,0 320,0 320,480 0,480" />
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
  <rect x="2" y="2" width="316" height="476" fill="#f2f2f2" stroke="#1698d9" stroke-width="4" rx="10" clip-path="url(#gon)"/>
  <line x1="2" y1="45" x2="45" y2="2" stroke="#1698d9" stroke-width="4" /> 
</svg>
```

Comment: Молодец, пацан!:))) 
Лучше занесите clipPath в `</defs>`, а ещё это можно решить с помощью псевдоэлементов

Comment: Исправил, дабы увидели, что я имел ввиду

Comment: Да. Дополнительная svg такое себе решения. Спасибо. И решение на псевдоэлементах у меня тоже реализовано, но мне принципиально было сделать на svg https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VXKPXY

Comment: @St1myL а как решить с помощью псевдоэлмементов?

Comment: Дал ответ, если он вам помог - поставьте плюс и чекбокс(решение)