# Как сделать скошенный угол у прямоугольника?

Tags: html, css, css3, svg, clip-path

Необходимо карточке, с `border`'ом и фоном (всё на `css`), сделать срез у верхнего левого угла и, чтобы у него был такой же `border`. Пробовал `clip-path`. Возможно нужно использовать псевдоэлемент или SVG?

[image: карточка товара]

```css
.Card {
    margin: 23px 0 0 80px;
    width: 320px;
    height: 480px;
    border: 4px solid #2ea8e6;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: #f2f2f2; 
    overflow: hidden;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    clip-path: polygon(15% 0, 100% 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 100% 100%, 0 100%, 0 100%, 0 10%);
}
```

Comment: Подобный вопрос был задан ранее — https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/800660/280567

Comment: Почитайте справку: [Что делать с ответами на мой вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Решение через `CSS3`:**

Это можно сделать при помощи `CSS3` `clip-path`, но [согласно документации](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path) в `Safari (WebKit)`, в `Edge` и в `Internet Explorer` это в данное время работать не будет.

Для того чтобы это сделать нам понадобится 2 прямоугольника (`div`), которые лежат один в другом. Внутренний прямоугольник расположен с помощью `position: absolute` сверху, а внешний выступает в качестве обводки (`border`), т.к. на `4px` (x2) больше внутреннего. Оба они обрезаются с помощью `CSS3` `clip-path`.

Подробнее о свойстве `clip-path` [читайте тут](https://getinstance.info/articles/css/making-sense-of-clip-path/).

```css
.card-border
{
    margin:14px;
    position: relative;
    width: 328px;
    height: 488px;
    background-color: #2ea8e6;
    border-radius: 14px;
    clip-path: polygon(15% 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%, 0 10%);
}
.card
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 4px; /* соответствует ширине border */
    left: 4px; /* соответствует ширине border */
    width: 320px; /* container width - (ширина border * 2) */
    height: 480px; /* container height - (ширина border * 2) */
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
    border-radius: 11px;
    clip-path: polygon(14.7% 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%, 0 9.7%);
}
```

```html
<div class="card-border">
    <div class="card"></div>
</div>
```

Обратите внимание на то, что значения у внутреннего `clip-path: polygon` должны быть немного меньше.

**Решение через `SVG`:**

Другое решение с помощью `SVG` `clip-path` более предпочтительнее, т. к. работает в большинстве современных обозревателях сети. Вы можете `SVG` файл применить в качестве `background` для `div`, в котором будут ваши данные.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" width="320" height="480">
<defs>
    <clipPath id="cp">
        <polygon points="45,0 320,0 320,480 0,480 0,48"/>
    </clipPath>
</defs>
<g stroke="#2ea8e6" stroke-width="4">
    <rect x="2" y="2" rx="14" clip-path="url(#cp)" width="316" height="476" fill="#f2f2f2"/>
    <line x1="2" y1="48" x2="45" y2="2"/>
</g>
</svg>
```

Comment: @Dmitry, вас мой ответ не устраивает? Почему нет отклика?

Comment: картинку добавьте для обрезки вместо серого прямоугольника, тогда может автор откликнется. От меня (+)

Comment: Спасибо большое. Сделал через before